# Is it possible to bind business logic in an anchor? (Or render a div in a h:commandLink)?

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to make a clickable div with some business logic in JSF like in static HTML anchor

Static HTML:

```
<a href="some action">
   <div>
      <img>some image</img>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
</a>
```

My question is how to do it with h:commandLink
I've tried something like this, but apparently it does not work

```
<h:commandLink action="backing bean method" 
value="<div>blablabla</div>" />
```

Comment: Didn't you try `<h:commandLink action="backing bean method" 
><div>blablabla</div></h:commandLink>`?

Comment: Thanks! Seems that I asked a stupid question